# Setting up Default Description Template on P4 Client

Tags: perforce

While creating new changelist is there a way that I can create default description template. So whenever I will create new changelist I want some of the details to be pre-populated on my p4 client. 
Below is an example to prepopulated template that I would like to have:

```
Summary: 
Fix: 
Impact:
Testing:
Unit Testing: 
Documentation:
QA: 
Localization: 
Jira-Id:
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this for all users on the server, set up a `form-out` trigger on the `change` form and replace the default template with your own template.  The simplest possible version of this is a `sed` one-liner:

```
Triggers: 
    form-out change "sed -i s/<.*>/fnord/ %formfile%"
```

You can replace this with something arbitrarily complex (maybe you want to modify the template per user, etc.)

If you want to just do it for yourself on your own client machine, do it in your editor (e.g. have a macro that replaces `<enter description here>` with your template).  If you can't do it in your editor, you can do it outside your editor by wrapping it in a script that does something like:

```
sed -i s/<.*>/fnord/ $1
vi $1
```

and then do:

```
p4 set P4EDITOR=my-wrapper.sh
```

Comment: I believe the server-side trigger will work for all users, and will work in tools besides the p4 command line (e.g., P4Win, P4V, ...). The client-side solutions are nice, too, thanks for providing them!

Comment: @Sam Stafford .. Thanks for your response.  Yes this is just for my P4 client on my machine. So I need to write the script first and then add the template there? .. Sorry I did not get the solution.

Comment: When you run `p4 submit` it opens the changelist description in your text editor, so the way to customize the changelist description is to customize your text editor.  Writing a wrapper script is one way to do that but I can't give you a very precise solution since I don't know what editor you're using or even what platform you're on.