# Perforce triggers objecting to syntax (validation failed: sed: -e expression#1 char 16: unterminated `s' command)

Tags: sed, perforce, p4v

I'm currently encountering an issue with p4 where a trigger to change the default text of a change list commit is throwing: 'patchnotes01' validation failed: sed: -e expression#1 char 16: unterminated `s' command

The command in question being added to triggers:

`Triggers: patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -i s/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:\n\n<**External Notes**>:/ %formfile%"`

Even a much more straight forward case:

`Triggers: patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -i s/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:/ %formfile%"`

yields the same issues/error.

I'm not entirely sure what its objecting to as the sed expression is valid. Ive used [Setting up Default Description Template on P4 Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861500/setting-up-default-description-template-on-p4-client) as my guide since the Helix documentation was lacking for a direct example.

The expectation was that the default commit message of `<enter description>`

is changed to

```
<Internal Notes>:

<**External Notes**>:
```

**EDIT (Additional info):**

Ive managed to get it to a point where it doesnt error out BUT any attempt to use single quotes to specify the substitution like

`patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -i 's/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:<External Notes>:/' %formfile%"`

Will fail with `validation failed: sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated address regex`

Any attempt to use \n (or any \character) for a new line will yield `` validation failed: sed: -e expression#1 char 16: unterminated `s' command ``

HOWEVER:
`patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -i s/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:<External Notes>:/ %formfile%"`

will return fine albeit, suboptimal as

```
<Internal_Notes>:<External_Notes>:
```

Which is lacking the newline for readability.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm guessing the script part gets interpreted by the shell since it's not quoted.

Comment: It is processed however the trigger file is processed. According to the documentation I could run a script in that space rather than a direct command like sed, but that overhead is something Id prefer to avoid if possible. https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.trigger.table.fields.html

Comment: Look at this part of your trigger: `s/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:/` - As you can see there is a space in there. That will make `sed` receive the script in two parts instead of one. `s/<.*>/<Internal` and `Notes>:/` - There's also a good chance that `<`, `>`, `.` and `*` are interpreted by the shell, depending on the shell. In a Un*x environment, I'd try `"sed -i 's/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:/' %formfile%"` - but I think you're using Windows, and I don't know how to do it there. You could try with the quotes I added and see if it helps though.

Comment: The system that actually runs the triggers should be the linux server from what I recall from the documentation. I am triggering said file to open with p4 triggers on my local windows machine. Attempting:  patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -i 's/<.*>/<Internal Notes>:/' %formfile%" yielded the error: patchnotes01' validation failed: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: Ok, that's better. Try changing `-i` to `-iE` for extended regex - and keep the single quotes. You may want to change `.*` to `[^>]*` too btw

Comment: No dice. patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -iE 's/<[^>]*>/<Internal\sNotes>:/' %formfile%"  Yields: 'patchnotes01' validation failed: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -i s/<.*>/<Internal\sNotes>:/ %formfile%" didnt error out but also didnt do what it was suppose to (seems like the default text may have been overwritten so theres nothing to target now)

Comment: Did you change `.*` to what I suggested?

Comment: Everything after `validation error:` is what's being printed by `sed`, not Perforce.   You may want to stick some `%quote%`s around the regex.

Comment: If you mean different quotes around the regex expression itself, tried it with no improvement. Added new data to original post.

Comment: Saw what you were referring to with %quote%, but unfortunately, even tho just adding them around the regex is fine, it still ignores \n when placed between <Internal_notes>: and <External_notes>: and throws an error instead: ```Error parsing form text; check form-out triggers?
Error detected at line 31.
Unknown field name '<External_Notes>'.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a solution that is convoluted but works.
\n can be use IF and ONLY IF the regex substitution expression is:

1. Surrounded by %quote%
2. there are spaces around the \n character

Example of what finally worked:

`patchnotes01 form-out change "sed -iE %quote%s/<.*>/[Internal_Notes]:  \n\n [External_Notes]:   /%quote% %formfile%"`

Any other permutation will fail when trying to use \ characters with a nonhelpful:

```
Error parsing form text; check form-out triggers?
Error detected at line 30.
Unknown field name '[External_Notes]'.
```